# Pausar script antes de terminar, en Latino

Tags: latino

Deseo detener/pausar la ejecución de un script antes de que acabe el script de ejecutarse o se cierre la ventana (similar al "Press key to continue" en C y otros lenguajes).

No encuentro referencias a un comando similar en la documentación.

Comment: Desconocia la existencia de este lenguaje y veo que en stackoverflow solo hay 3 preguntas sobre dicho lenguaje y 2 son tuyas.
Te recomiendo visitar su [documentacion oficial](https://github.com/lenguaje-latino/latino) donde deberias encontrar lo que buscas

Comment: @Juanma tmbn hay una pagina de github pero los adm. no le dan mucho seguimiento. Es un lenguaje de aprendizaje pero es igual de capaz a muchos otros. Yo quiero estudiarlo mas porque soy diseñador grafico no programador.

Comment: Si eso es lo que he visto, no tiene mucho mantenimiento, si no tienes un interes especial en èl y solo quieres un lenguaje  facil de aprender te recomiendo Python( Latino esta basado en èl) o C.  Iniciarte en un lenguaje con poco mantenimiento o documentación puede ser desmotivador.

Comment: @juama ok gracias por el consejo.. lo investigaré un poco

Comment: @Juanma C es un lenguaje de bajo nivel, hay muchos otros lenguajes más fáciles de aprender.

Comment: Por supuesto, pero yo he recomendado  alternativas en lenguajes multiproposito como el que èl ya estaba estudiando. Además C es (junto con Python) de los lenguajes mas recomendados para principiantes y es tambien el primer lenguaje que se enseña en cualquier carrera o fp de informática.

Comment: te responderia pero las respuestas estan bloqueadas. El comando en la documentacion es https://manual.lenguajelatino.org/es/latest/funciones/leer.html

Comment: Hola @MarceloFavioPalaciosSolrzan, al final de tu código, prueba colocando el siguiente comando para detener tu código igual como lo harías en C. el comando es: **leer()** aqui un enlace: https://manual.lenguajelatino.org/es/stable/funciones/leer.html